# Reading a text file from HDFS in Scala/Spark

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I am using Scala and Spark and want to read in an XML file as a single string.
I'm struggling to find a neat Scala-ish way to do this.

My first thought was to use

```
val fileContents: RDD[String] = sparkContext.textfile(pathToFile)
val combinedContents: String = fileContents.reduce((line1, line2) => line1 + line2)
```

But I am concerned about this maintaining the order of lines that is important to keep the integrity of the xml contained within the string.

Other stuff I have found online to read files in HDFS involve using deprecated methods so I want to avoid those. Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

Comment: If I can I'd like to avoid using non standard libraries as this comes with a cost (support, approvals with management, etc)

Also the xml management comes later in the application, I'm required to provide a string. I don't really care that it's xml at the moment, it's just to illustrate that ordering of lines is important.

Comment: Why not `fileContents.collect` then?

Comment: I was concerned that it was the sparkContext.textfile stage that would cause order to be lost however so initial experiments appear to suggest otherwise and fileContents.collect.mkString seems to work. If so, great, thanks!

Was it the reduce that caused order to fall apart or have i just not been able to repeat .textfile from breaking ordering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sc.textFile returns an RDD with "sorted lines".
Note that if you have multiples files in provided path, files will be assigned to partitions also in alphabetical order (of the name of the file).
So, as a conclusion, sc.textFile keeps the order of the lines.

As far as I can check reviewing implementation of collect() method, order is also kept, so there is no reason to not use directly:

`sc.textFile(pathToFile).collect()`

This should work.

However, if you want to be prepared for a different implementation of collect (since in documentation it is not guaranteed to keep the order) the solution I would propose is using RDD method zipWithIndex that is philosophically equivalent to scala's method with the same name.

So I would do something like this:

`sc.textFile(pathToFile).zipWithIndex().collect().sortBy(_._2).map(_._1)`

Comment: sc.textFile(pathToFile).collect() is what I went with. Seems like my concerns about order  from textFile() were unfounded.

Comment: As far as I know .collect() is not ideal when dealing with large files. How would you approach the problem with larger files?

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. Read whole file with:

`sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(filePath)`

But looks like overhead if you don't have many such files.

2. Get HDFS file system object, and read file as InputStream. A lot of examples available: [HDFS FileSystems API example](https://gist.github.com/ashrithr/f7899fdfd36ee800f151)